# Api annotation's description is deprecated

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-2.0, springfox

In Swagger, the [`@Api`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/io.swagger/swagger-annotations/1.6.2/io/swagger/annotations/Api.html) annotation's [`description`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/io.swagger/swagger-annotations/1.6.2/io/swagger/annotations/Api.html#description--) element is deprecated.

> **Deprecated.**
> Not used in 1.5.X, kept for legacy support.

Is there a newer way of providing the description?

Comment: Which Version do you refer to?

Comment: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Annotations-1.5.X or maybe http://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/current/apidocs/index.html?io/swagger/annotations/Api.html might help

Comment: @Jens I am using 2.4.0 version (springfox)

Comment: As i can see, only three attibutes are deprecated

Comment: @Jens, if it is deprecated, it means that there is a newer alternative, what is that?

Comment: Deprecated means, that it won't be used any more in a later version. It doesn't necessarily mean, that there is a newer alternative.

Comment: @dunni ohh I see, Thanks :)

Comment: @SoumitriPattnaik you found any solution ?

Answer (score 62):

I found two solutions for Spring Boot application:

***1. [Swagger 2](https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api) based:***

Firstly, use the `tags` method for specify the tags definitions in your `Docket` bean:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class Swagger2Config {
    
    public static final String TAG_1 = "tag1";

    @Bean
    public Docket productApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("my.package")).build()
                .tags(new Tag(TAG_1, "Tag 1 description."))
                // Other tags here...
                .apiInfo(apiInfo());
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder().title("My API").version("1.0.0").build();
    }
}
```

After, in `RestController` just add the `@Api` annotation with one (or more) of the your tags:

```java
@Api(tags = { SwaggerConfig.TAG_1 })
@RestController
@RequestMapping("tag1-domain")
public class Tag1RestController { ... }
```

***2. [Swagger 3](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-openapi-documentation) based (OpenAPI):***

Similarly, use the `addTagsItem` method for specify the tags definitions in your `OpenAPI` bean:

```java
@Configuration
public class OpenApiConfig {

    public static final String TAG_1 = "tag1";

    @Bean
    public OpenAPI customOpenAPI() {
        final Info info = new Info()
                .title("My API")
                .description("My API description.")
                .version("1.0.0");

        return new OpenAPI().components(new Components())
                .addTagsItem(createTag(TAG_1, "Tag 1 description."))
                // Other tags here...
                .info(info);
    }

    private Tag createTag(String name, String description) {
        final Tag tag = new Tag();
        tag.setName(name);
        tag.setDescription(description);
        return tag;
    }

}
```

Finally, in `RestController` just add the `@Tag` annotation:

```java
@Tag(name = OpenApiConfig.TAG_1)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("tag1-domain")
public class Tag1RestController { ... }
```

Comment: Description of Tag not coming on swagger UI

Comment: @Kick - It does if you use a new enough version of Swagger (eg. 2.9.x)

Comment: @falvojr - Perfect. However if there is any way if we can reduced font size?

Comment: Great, This worked for me too. However, I am wondering if there is any way to add line breaks in the description. I tried putting \n and <br>

Comment: This helped for 2.9.2 version!

Comment: Don't you face the `new io.swagger.annotations.Tag` - is abstract, cannot be instantiated? Should be `springfox.documentation.service.Tag`.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the `springfox.documentation.service.Tag`, following the `tags` (builder method) signature.

Comment: so I have to add description inside Swagger2Config. So If I have 20 controllers I have to put all of them in the Swagger2Config. IMHO it would be better to have it inside the same controller

Answer (score 19):

This is the correct way to add description to your Swagger API documentation for Swagger v1.5:

```java
@Api(tags = {"Swagger Resource"})
@SwaggerDefinition(tags = {
    @Tag(name = "Swagger Resource", description = "Write description here")
})
public class ... {
}
```

Comment: This looks like a good way to do it, but what if you are reusing the tag on multiple APIs ? where would u put SwaggerDefinition ? I've tried to put it on my SwaggerConfig bean, but it was not taken into account. Only the programatically way worked for me.

Comment: @zhuguowei, Did you found the way to use it in 2.9.2? Help me if you know how to use it in a 2.9.2 version.

Comment: @ShivarajaHN please see falvojr 's answer

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution does not work, see https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/1476.

Comment: GitHub issue for this solution not working: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/3737

Comment: the idea is correct, but not the implementation, for correct implementation see `1. Swagger 2 based:` from falvojr - set `@Api(tags = {"User"})` - that User appears in Swagger page and in SwaggerConfig.java for new Docket() after build add `.tags(new Tag("User", "some user actions");`

Answer (score 16):

The reason why it's deprecated is that previous Swagger versions (1.x) used the `@Api` description annotation to group operations.

In the Swagger 2.0 specification, the notion of `tags` was created and made a more flexible grouping mechanism.  To be API compliant, the `description` field was retained so upgrades would be easy, but the correct way to add a description is though the `tags` attribute, which should reference a `@Tag` annotation.  The `@Tag` allows you to provide a description and also external links, etc.

Comment: An example would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I tried above solutions but they didn't work for me.

To add a title and description to the documentation you create **ApiInfo** and **Contact** objects like in example below.
Then you simply add **apiInfo** object to your Swagger Docket.

```
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
import springfox.documentation.service.Contact;

@EnableSwagger2
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig {

  private Contact contact = new Contact("", "", "");
  private ApiInfo apiInfo = new ApiInfo(
      "Backoffice API documentation",
      "This page documents Backoffice RESTful Web Service Endpoints",
      "1.0",
      "",
      contact,
      "",
      "");

  @Bean
  public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
        .apiInfo(apiInfo)
        .select()
        .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage(
            PaymentsController.class.getPackage().getName()
        ))
        .paths(PathSelectors.ant("/api/v1/payments" + "/**"))
        .build()
        .useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
        .globalOperationParameters(
            newArrayList(new ParameterBuilder()
                .name("x-authorization")
                .description("X-Authorization")
                .modelRef(new ModelRef("string"))
                .parameterType("header")
                .required(false)
                .build()));
  }
}
```

Above code produces a description like in a screenshot below.

[image: screenshot of swagger-ui page produced by code above]

Comment: I've added your image - pending review... but it seems you may have answered another question here! The question is about `description` attribute of `@Api` annotation - which was being rendered per class/tag/group of entry points, not the whole application's API as in your screenshot

Answer (score 1):

I too wondered what to do about uses of the deprecated `description` (showing up as warnings in my IDE).

Well, on closer inspection it turned out that `description` **is not used anywhere in Swagger UI**. After that the solution (in our case*) became clear: simply remove those descriptions.

(*In our codebase, with clean class and method names etc, there was certainly no need for such "API descriptions" for the reader of the code. I would have tolerated having these bits of Swagger-related noise in the codebase if they added some value in Swagger UI, but since they didn't, the only sensible thing was to throw them away.)

Answer (score 1):

I found that the following works by combining both the `@Api` and `@Tag` annotations building off of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38113193/2066723).

The value within the tags field of the `@Api` annotation needs to match the value within the name field of the `@Tag` annotation.

```java
@Api(tags = "Controller API")
@Tag(name = "Controller API", description = "This controller performs API operations")
public class ReportStatusConsumerController {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

An old question but may help using swagger 3

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
    // Swagger configuration
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {

        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .apiInfo( this.apiInfo())
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder().title("API Reference").version("1.0.0")
                .description("something")
                .license("Apache 2.0")
                .build();
    }

    public void addResouceHandler(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }
}
```