# Swagger UI add description next to the @Api value

Tags: java, web-services, swagger, swagger-ui

I have a web service with several paths. I want to add a description to each one. I added the name using @Api(value = "serviceName1") however the description attribute is deprecated and even if i use it it is not showing in Swagger UI. I even tried the SwaggerDefinition annotation and filled the description attribute in it with no result displayed:

```
@SwaggerDefinition(
 info = @Info(
       description = "text here ", title = "", version = ""))
```

I tried to create in the same way a tag with description and it didn't work as well.

Can anyone help to find any way to be able to add a note or description to the service similarly to the way we add a note to the Api Operation.

Comment: can you share content of your swagger file? at least some part where you need to add description

Comment: I'm not sure to understand well. Why don't you use ApiOperation ?

Comment: Current class code:

_@Api(value = "Provisioning")
@Path("{userId}/provisioning/")
@EnterprisePermissions(enterprisePermissions = Permissions.PROVISIONING_PERMISSION)
public class ProvisioningService extends BaseService
{....}_

Comment: Swagger file part that needs to include description:

_"tags" : [ {
    "name" : "DAP"
  }, {
    "name" : "JKP"
  }, {
    "name" : "Provisioning"
  } ],_

Comment: @B.Bri i am already using ApiOperation with its notes but i need to add something similar to the notes attributes on the class level (on the service or tag level)

Comment: hope this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38074936/api-annotaions-description-is-deprecated/38113193#38113193

Comment: Does using the tag will display the description in the swagger UI? or only in the JSON?