# How to add description to API controller in Swagger 1.5.20?

Tags: java, swagger

I'm trying to provide formatted description to a controller in Swagger. However I can't find any annotation that enables it. Currently it looks like this:

```
@Api(tags = {"Change timezone"})
```

[image]

However I would like to provide meaningful description. The `description` parameter withing `@Api` is deprecated.

Comment: you mean method description? or controller description?

Comment: Which version are you using. Personnaly I use l5-swagger and the annotations are `@OA`

Comment: @Boug Controller.

Comment: @J-Dumas Swagger 1.5.20.

Comment: here it is https://stackoverflow.com/a/50213515/7237884

Comment: @Boug Read about it, it is a bug, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that, there is a hole with this deprecation. This feature has been deprecated but no other Annotation has replaced that functionality.

For now it seems that you can only add description programmatically

```
@Bean 
public Docket commonDocketConfig() { 

 return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2) .select() 
       .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.company")) 
       .paths(PathSelectors.any()) 
       .build() .apiInfo(apiEndPointsInfo()) 
       .tags(new Tag("Change timezone", "your description")); 
 }
```

Issue can be tracked here

[@Api description deprecated without any alternative](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/1476)

You can try also with

```
@Api(tags = {"Change timezone"})
@SwaggerDefinition(tags = {
        @Tag(name = "Change timezone", description = "your Description")
})
public class YourController {
}
```

This annotation however already has an open bug for not behaving correctly [@SwaggerDefinition bug](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/3737)

Comment: thanks, works perfect the `@SwaggerDefinition`

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like yours is a PUT operation, try doing something like this. You can also write it like this:

```
@OA(
    @PUT(
        tags = {"Change timezone"},
        description = "Your description here",
        etc...
    )
)
```

[image: Swagger PUT operation tags]

Here is the link to where I took the image: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Annotations#operation
Try reading more on it there.

Comment: I don't want to describe controller action but controller itself it is stated in the question.